# Sort table using tablesorter and change background on hovering the even and odd rows

Tags: html, html-table, hover, mouseover, tablesorter

http://jsfiddle.net/6ecr4/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".items").tablesorter();
    $('.items tr:even').addClass('ItemEvenRow');

    $('.items tr').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("ItemRowHover");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ItemRowHover");
    });
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<table class="items"> 
<thead> 
<tr class=""> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr>  
    <td >Bach</td> 
    <td >Frank</td> 
    <td >fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td >$50.00</td> 
    <td >http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr > 
    <td  >Doe</td> 
    <td >Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td  >$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

The even rows do not possess the hover, but only the odd ones.
Require both, even, as well as, odd rows to change their background on mouse-over.
The headers should be as they are without any changes.

Answer (score 1):

The hover isn't working on even rows because of css precedence. Make the selector more specific like this (add a `tr` in front; [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ecr4/12/)):

```
tr.ItemRowHover  {background-color:#A00000; }
```

Comment: sir, can you please elaborate 'css precdence'

Comment: also I don't need hover on the headers

Comment: See this article for more details on CSS precendence (or specificity): http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/